# A rhyming riddle which is really hard

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I just came up with this rhyming riddle, and I don't know if anybody can solve this:

> I end with a letter,
> My prefix is far better.
> My suffix am found in a mill,
> But I am not just nil.

Ok, at first this really makes 0 sense and looks like there could be many answers, but it really just has 1 answer.
One tip: **The answer is hidden in the riddle.**

#### Hint 1:

> The answer is a place.

#### Hint 2:

> The first line gives a hint about the third line.
> But you still need the second letter to solve it.
> The last line is almost useless.
> One more: The second line solves 3/4 of the riddle

Note: If nobody answers this is 2 weeks, I will give another hint.

### Can you solve this?

Comment: Is there any reason you used mathjax here? That increases the loading time of the page and harms accessibility -- you shouldn't use it just for formatting unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Deusovi No, I just wanted to change the font. Mathjax has many fonts.

Comment: _One tip: The answer is hidden in the riddle._ Never knew about that tip!

Comment: Does it have something to do with binary? "0 sense" and "1 answer"

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I'm really interested in binary, but, sorry I didn't see the answer. ;-). Just a suggestion: [Here](https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.IgpJ-y8c9G5DActCDidYkQHaFj&pid=Api) is a better profile picture passing to  you're username

Comment: @math - Haha, thanks! I may end up using that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> farm

---

How I figured it out:

> **First premise: "The answer is hidden in the riddle."**
>  Whatever it is, it should be seen in verbatim inside the riddle.

> **Second premise: "The answer is a place."**
>  This doesn't say anything. If I were to follow that hint, I'd never find out. It made sense after I went through the second hint, though.

> **Third premise: "The first line gives a hint about the third line."**
>  The first lines says *"I end with a letter,"* and the third line says *"My suffix am found in a mill,"*. I figured the suffix stated in the first line must be only one letter. The fourth line "But I am not just nil." and the strange use of "am" in "am found" lead me to just guess it was *m*.

> **Fourth premise: "The last line is almost useless."**
>  This hint seems useless. Is this a riddle inside the riddle or an internal joke?

> **Fifth premise: "One more: The second line solves 3/4 of the riddle"**
>  The second line is *"My prefix is far better."* and I've been told by the first premise that the answer is hidden in the riddle. So it must be literally saying what the prefix is, don't it? The word after "is" happens to be "far", which if combined with "m" becomes **farm**. This may be a place. Also if the answer has four letters then 3/4 of the answer is three letters, and "far" is in the second line.

Comment: rot13 Whfg ernq gur bgure nafjref abj naq svtherq fbzrbar nyernql nafjrerq gur fnzr. tt ab er.

Comment: It's ok that you didn't see the other one(You know once somebody was just 3 minutes [earlier than me](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6939/should-my-answer-be-deleted-if-there-is-a-similar-identical-answer)). Very nice answer. I still upvoted and marked it as a best answer because I liked the way you solved it with the hints. ;-) Keep it up.

Answer (score 5):

I'm new here so I don't know if such wild guesses are allowed, but here's my guess

> Farm

I end in a letter

> Ends in **m**

My prefix is far better.

> My prefix is **far** better

My suffix am found in a mill

> **am** when pronounced sounds like the letter **M** and is found in the word **m**ill

The answer is a place.

> Last time I checked, a farm was a place

The first line gives a hint about the third line.

> First line tells that the suffix mentioned in the third line is a letter

But you still need the second letter to solve it.

No idea about this one

The second line solves 3/4 of the riddle

> second line gives three out of the four letters (f - a - r)

Comment: Great (wild) guess. ;-) Exactly what I thought! Get ready to get 291 rep!

Comment: @math Thanks! And don't forget to give another hint after 2 weeks since `nobody` solved it within 2 weeks

Comment: Nice joke, nobody ;-)

Answer (score 4):

partial answer, but it doesn't really makes sense

maybe it's

> null

I end with a letter,

> don't know yet

My prefix is far better.

> nu, sounds like "new", is new really better than old though?

My suffix am found in a mill,

> ll is found in "mill"

But I am not just nil.

> "nil" is used to represent a null pointer to an Objective-C class, "null" for the rest (i had to check google for this, knew some languages had both null and nil, but didn't know they where different haha)

edit: just saw the hint, so it really doesn't make sense now, but maybe some of my reasoning is correct

Comment: Almost did it, but it was also not what I thought.

Comment: Check it out, I added another hint. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Second Attempt

> **MAXI**

Because
I end with a letter,

> Ends in **I**

My prefix is far better.

> **MAX** - Maximum is the most

My suffix am found in a mill,

> **XI** or 11 - One could see it as miII, where II are two capital letters (ii)

But I am not just nil.

> Reversing **t nil** gives **lint** - def: staple cotton fiber used to make yarn.
>  So, not just lint but a [garment](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/maxi?s=t)

Hints

> - [Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxi_(Canadian_supermarket)) - MAXI - a Supermarket Chain
>  - Hidden in  the riddle - My suff **ix am** found in a mill,(*reverse*)
>  - **MAX** is 3/4 of the word **MAXI**

Previous Answer

> **LIMA**

Because
I end with a letter,

> LIM**A** - Ends in "A" letter

My prefix is far better.

> **LIM** - LIM can be the abbreviation for LIMIT which is the farthest.

My suffix am found in a mill,

> Perhaps a Millenial would say **IMA** instead of **I am** going to do something or **I am a** something.

But I am not just nil.

> Possibly the shape of a Lima bean or other bean **0** (outline almost looks like a zero)

One tip: The answer is hidden in the riddle.

> My suffix am found in - **a mil** - l, *reverse* - (hint) which is a place

Comment: Nice answer, but sorry no.

Comment: Check it out, I added another hint.

Comment: @math, rot13(V sbhaq nabgure ohg pna'g fbyvqvsl n cynpr. Naq vf orvat orggre lbhe bcvavba? V unira'g frra rvgure.yby)

Comment: If you want, you can add it as an answer.

Comment: But actually my answer is just 1 word.

Comment: My other guess wasn't going to be an actual word, more of a variable descriptor. So, I'm out.

Comment: Ok. Do you need another hint?

Comment: Nope. You already gave one today. Plus they can use some of these comments to possibly glean information.